# How to serialize a self created Object using kSOAP in Android

Tags: android, ksoap2, android-ksoap2, ksoap

i am doing some ksoap requests. Everything is working fine. But now I reached the point, where I have to pass a custom object which i created. Its called "Auftrag". It's just a simple POJO.

Try to pass it with "request.addProperty" ends in an error

```
02-26 14:47:32.995: W/System.err(14095): java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: kochtokrax.de.pojo.Auftrag@41a444d8
```

After spending a lot of time I found the "Marshalling solution". 
http://seesharpgears.blogspot.de/2010/11/implementing-ksoap-marshal-interface.html
This example is for the types "doubel" and "Date". Sadly this isn't working for my object.
Can someone help me how I have to deal in this case?

Here is the way I am calling the service:

```
  PropertyInfo nos =new PropertyInfo();
  nos.setName("Auftrag");
  nos.setType(AuftragMarshall.class);

    // Use this to add parameters
    request.addProperty("Auftrag", auftrag);
    request.addProperty("DruckerBar", druckerBar);
    request.addProperty("DruckerKueche", druckerKueche);

    // Declare the version of the SOAP request
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoaperializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = false;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    AuftragMarshall marshall = new AuftragMarshall();
    marshall.register(envelope);
```

Comment: please, add class `Auftrag`.

Answer (score 1):

Class `Auftrag` must implements `KvmSerializable`.

You haven't correctly set value for `nos`, so:

```
PropertyInfo nos = new PropertyInfo();
nos.setName("Auftrag");
nos.setType(AuftragMarshall.class);
nos.setValue(auftragObj);
```

Because you've set type of `PropertyInfo` to `Auftrag`. But later you add `DruckerBar` and  `DruckerKueche`. I suppose it is different classes. And it isn't correct.

I solve similar problem like you and marshalling doesn't work also for me. I solved it with custom mappers. I firstly map desired object to object of class with implementation `KvmSerializable` and then send it through web service.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to see [Adding an array of complex objects to the request](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/CodingTipsAndTricks#Adding_an_array_of_complex_objects_to_the_request).